# MySql datetime field in HTML/php table is only showing date when using form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, datetime

I have a `datetime` MySql field named `down_stamp` that I have populating an HTML table via php:

```
<? $sql_el = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE loc_id = '$lid'";
$result_el = mysql_query($sql_el);
while ($row_el = mysql_fetch_array($result_el)) {
?>
<tr>
  <td><?=$row_el['down_stamp']?></td>
</tr>
</form>
<? } ?>
```

This produces results in the format I'd like: `2013-09-15 08:30:00`. However, I'd like to make this field modifiable, so if I just convert it into a form element like this:

```
<form name="fm_editevent" method="post">
<tr>
  <td><input name="down_stamp_ed" required="required" value=<? echo $row_el['down_stamp']; ?> type="text"></td>
  <td><input value="Update" type="submit" name="update_el"></td>     
</tr>
</form>
<? } ?>
```

Then the `down_stamp` field only displays the date: `2013-09-15`. I don't think it's a width issue as there's plenty of room in the text box. I tried adding `<td width=100>` (twas a guess). I also tried to declare the time in php when expanding the variable, which just gave me an error and the date `1970-01-01 01:33:33`

```
<td><input name="down_stamp_ed" required="required" value=<? echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row_el['down_stamp']);?> ></td>
```

How can I get the full datetime field data to echo in this form text box?

Comment: you are missing the quotes `value="<? echo $row_el['down_stamp']; ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotation marks...

Use:

```
<td><input name="down_stamp_ed" required="required" value="<? echo $row_el['down_stamp']; ?>" type="text"></td>
```

(without the quotation marks the result would look like this:

```
<td><input name="down_stamp_ed" required="required" value=2013-09-15 01:33:33 type="text"></td>
```

and just because you're lucky your browser interprets "2013-09-15" as the value of the field ;-)

Comment: Of course. Thank you. Sometimes it's something so simple that I make so complicated. Forest/Trees.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap value in `"` :

```
<form name="fm_editevent" method="post">
<tr>
  <td><input name="down_stamp_ed" value="<? echo $row_el['down_stamp']; ?>" type="text" required></td>
  <td><input value="Update" type="submit" name="update_el"></td>     
</tr>
</form>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quote the `value` attribute, e.g:

```
echo "< .... value=\"$date_from_db\">";
```

Without them, you're generating

```
... value=2014-10-21 15:16:00
```

which is parsed as an attribute "value" whose value is `2014-10-21`, and an unknown/illegal attribute "15:16:00".